# 'Undefined index' error for session - php

Tags: php, session

I am using session for my login section. When a user logged on, I try to give username from the session. My code works well but in my error_log file, I have the following errors. Can you help me to fix the problem?

***error_log.php***

```
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:20 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login_user_admin in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/session.php on line 5
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:20 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login_user_admin in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php on line 35
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:20 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php on line 37
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:20 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php on line 38
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:28 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login_user_admin in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/session.php on line 5
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:28 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login_user_admin in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php on line 35
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:28 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php on line 37
[01-Sep-2018 01:57:28 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in /home/cp31481/public_html/admin/index.php:38
```

***session.php***

```
<?php
session_start();
include "db.php";
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user_admin'];
$ses_sql = "select username from users where type = 'admin' AND username='$user_check'";
$result = $connection->query($ses_sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$login_session = $row['username'];
if (!isset($login_session)) {
    mysqli_close($connection);
    header('Location: admin.php');
}
```

***index.php***

```
<?php
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user_admin'];
$sql = "select name,img from users where type = 'admin' AND username='$user_check'";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$name = $row['name'];
$img = $row['img'];

echo "<img src='../img/$img' alt ='avatar'>";
echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are no checking if "login_user_admin" exist in $_SESSION or not. Change `$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user_admin'];` to this one

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user_admin'])){
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user_admin'];
}else{
    $user_check = null;
}
```

You can always check if index exist in $_SESSION using isset. When you try to get value from $_SESSION and that index does not exist in $_SESSION, script raises a notice error, which is sometime hidden due to your error settings

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user_admin'])){
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user_admin'];
    $sql = "select name,img from users where type = 'admin' AND username='$user_check'";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $row['name'];
    $img = $row['img'];
}else{
    $img = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check User Session

Try this :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user_admin']))
{
    session_destroy();
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php';</script>";
    exit;
}
```